# iOS TableViewController doesn't display

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a UIViewController with a TableView inside which displays stuff from the server my code is this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [UserDefaults instance];
    [Async activitiesForPersonId:[userDefaults objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_PERSONID]
                     unionId:[userDefaults objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_UNIONID]
                    callback:^(NSArray *activities){
                        if(activities && [activities count] != 0){
                            NSLog(@"%hhd",[NSThread isMainThread]); //1
                            NSLog(@"%i", [activities count]); //16
                            self.activities = activities;
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"What the ...."); //Doesn't get printed
                        }
                    }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return [self.activities count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"CalendarActivity";
    CalendarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    return cell;
}
```

How come nothing displays on the screen. When I change the [self.activities count] to for example hard coded 5, it displays 5 cells. So I guess I have set the datasource correctly through IB. Also the data comes from another thread but returns it on the main thread so that probably isn't the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually setting anything in the cells. For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    // Set up cell stuff
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title For Cell";

    return cell;
}
```

Edit:

You probably need to reload the tableView once the data is ready to be displayed, `[tableView reloadData];` should do this for you.

Comment: I know that, but atleast it should display my layout for the cell

Comment: Oh, in which case when your data is returned call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Are you kidding me lol haha. Fixed, lets call the problem to much hours behind the computer ;) Thanks, will accept in 8 min

Comment: No worries, happens to me all the time!

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebind the tableview in the callback that is executed when your async function completes:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [UserDefaults instance];
    [Async activitiesForPersonId:[userDefaults objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_PERSONID]
                     unionId:[userDefaults objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_UNIONID]
                    callback:^(NSArray *activities){
                        if(activities && [activities count] != 0){
                            NSLog(@"%hhd",[NSThread isMainThread]); //1
                            NSLog(@"%i", [activities count]); //16
                            self.activities = activities;

                             //add this line:
                            [self.tableView reloadData];

                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"What the ...."); //Doesn't get printed
                        }
                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also the data comes from another thread but returns it on the main thread so that probably isn't the problem either.

Actually, that is your problem.  If you add a few breakpoints I'm sure you will see numberOfRowsInSection being called before your async callback handler.  Reload your tableView data in the main thread at the end of your async callback block and you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [tableView reloadData];
Change your code in viewDidLoad:

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [UserDefaults instance];
        [Async activitiesForPersonId:[userDefaults objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_PERSONID]
                         unionId:[userDefaults objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_UNIONID]
                        callback:^(NSArray *activities){
                            if(activities && [activities count] != 0){
                                NSLog(@"%hhd",[NSThread isMainThread]); //1
                                NSLog(@"%i", [activities count]); //16
                                self.activities = activities;
                                // If your metod doesn't run on main thread call it on main tread:
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [tableView reloadData];
                                });
                               //Otherwise call just [tableView reloadData];
                            }else{
                                NSLog(@"What the ...."); //Doesn't get printed
                            }
                        }];
    }
```